# How can a Raspberry PI receives a struct from Arduino?

Tags: python, c, arduino, raspberry-pi

I am trying to find a solution to this problem for a few days and nothing worked for me so far. I have to mention thou that Python is not my strong point.

Anyway, I am trying to send a `typedef struct` using a LoRa transceiver(RFM95) that I programmed with the `Radiohead` library. The structure looks like this:

```
typedef struct {
    double temp;
    double hum;
} Payload;
```

I am able to receive the data on the raspberry side, but like an array of bytes.

```
Received: [0, 0, 228, 65, 154, 153, 65, 66]
```

How can I convert this into an object like `{temp: VALUE_OF_TEMP, hum: VALUE_OF_HUM}`?

Is there a way to do so like in C?
Example:

```
typedef struct {
    double temp;
    double hum;
} ReceivedData;
ReceivedData data;

data = *(Payload*)receivedBuffer;
```

Please help! I ran out of ideeas!

Comment: Have you had a look at the [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) module?

Comment: There are many JSON libraries you can use, but for a simple structure I'd probably just use brute force and `sprintf` the sucker.

Comment: Stealing the C++ tag, by the way. Doesn't look like you need it and it'll just wind up getting you answers that'll only apply to C++ and comments like, "Omigawd. Why are you typedefing structures? That's like ssssooooo 1980s."

Comment: @user4581301 going to the trouble of serializing to string for a signal like this seems weird. OP's approach of sending binary data on the wire makes a lot more sense. All they need to do is interpret it on the receiving end.

Comment: @Frank I looked at the struct module but I don't know what should I put at the `format` attribute.

Comment: @Frank `TypeError: a byte-like object is required, not 'list'`

Comment: @Andy95 that's more of an issue with how you are getting the data in the first place. Normally, a byte buffer "should" be what you are getting (depending on the means you are using). If all else fails you can use `bytearray()` to convert your list into a byte buffer. (also, if you are commenting on issues you are having implementing my answer, you should comment on the answer itself)

Comment: @Frank I might have read this wrong or put the too much emphasis on the request for `{temp: VALUE_OF_TEMP, hum: VALUE_OF_HUM}`.  Yes, it's more efficient to send binary, but the asker's having trouble writing a parser and for JSON, the parser's built right in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention what kind of Arduino you are using, I'm assuming that you are using an Arduino Uno or something with an 8-bit MCU. For Arduino with 8-bit MCU, the `double` is just like `float` consists of 4 bytes instead of 8 bytes in 32-bit MCU or Raspberry Pi.

So to unpack the struct on the RPI with Python, I think this is what you are looking for:

```
import struct

data = [0, 0, 228, 65, 154, 153, 65, 66]

bstr = bytearray(data)
result = struct.unpack("<ff", bstr)
print(result)
```

This would product the result as:

```
(28.5, 48.400001525878906)
```

I think these are the two values that you sent over the Arduino.

**Update**

If you are receiving data that consists of multiple data structs, you can use `iter_unpack()` method:

```
import struct
data = [0, 0, 228, 65, 154, 153, 65, 66, 0, 0, 228, 65, 154, 153, 65, 66, 0, 0, 228, 65, 154, 153, 65, 66]
bstr = bytearray(data)
results = struct.iter_unpack("<ff", bstr)
for result in results:
    print(result)
```

I would suggest you read the documentation of Python [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) in more details to take the full advantage of the library.

Comment: Yes, they are. 28 deg Celsius and 48,4% air himidity!

Comment: I owe you and Frank a beer :D

Comment: Cheer for that!

Comment: Here is a little upgrade. I managed to transform the byte array into the data I want. Now, if I try to send multiple such payloads, I will end up with a massive array. The payload data array is `[0, 0, 228, 65, 154, 153, 65, 66]`, but is one after the other(like this:`[0, 0, 228, 65, 154, 153, 65, 66, 0, 0, 228, 65, 154, 153, 65, 66, 0, 0, 228, 65, 154, 153, 65, 66]`). Is there a way that I can define the size of the data I want to extract form the array? The way unpack function works with the `<ff` parameter?

Comment: See my "update" on the answer regarding `iter_unpack`.

Answer (score 0):

That's fairly easy to do with the [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.unpack_from) module:

In your case, you are decoding two doubles, so the format is `dd`.

```py
from struct import unpack

def parse_payload(data_buffer):
  as_tuple = unpack('dd', data_buffer)
  return {
    "temp": as_tuple[0],
    "hum": as_tuple[1]
  }
```

Obviously, you should still do some validation and sanity checking beforehand, and you may have to deal with endianness issues, but this should be enough to get you going.

Comment: Yeah...I am still having some problems with the format that is accepting in unpack function. If I put the bytearray forcing, it says that unpack needs a buffer of 16 bytes. I will check it out further and hit you up if I solve it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Andy95 Well, each double is 8 bytes. So if you don't have a buffer of 16 bytes, then the data in your hands is not the data from your struct. (or at least, it's not a pair of doubles)

Comment: How can that be? If I change the struct with a char array or a uint8_t array, I receive the correct data. Same program.

Comment: Without the 4 headers, I receive an array with a length of eight.

Comment: @Andy95 I don't know what to tell you, each double has 8 bytes. That's kind of the start and end of it.

Comment: Thank you for you help! I will try to solve this issue. Maybe I will turn the payload into a char array and send it that way, thou is not optimal....

Comment: If you replace the `dd` with `<ff` it works flawlessly. Thanks Frank!

Answer (score 0):

try to use
#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct . . .
#pragma pack(pop)

for prevent byte arrange

Comment: Sorry! But I have no ideea of what you are talking about here...

Comment: @Andy, if you have a struct with mixed types, like `struct {double, short, char, double};` Then that pragma will make the struct look like what you'd expect on the wire. In your case, with just two doubles, it will have no effect.